# Clojure - Idiomatic Way To Fill A Vector While In A Loop

Tags: loops, vector, clojure

I have a requirement where upon receipt of a request, I have to fetch values from an external source, filter them and return the filtered values to the caller. I am accumulating the result (until it reaches the required size) by fetching a specified amount of records from the external source at a time. I managed to come up with a solution, but I am not sure if it is the most elegant or idiomatic way of doing it.

Please see the simulated code below, where the the make-response function has to return the first 50 odd numbers to the caller. (Note that this code may not handle the edge cases, but I think is good enough for demonstration purpose).

Maybe I should use ref instead of atom? Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

```
(defn fetch [start]
  (let [end (+ start 10)]
    (range start end)))

(defn take-good-ones [all]
  (filter odd? all))

(defn make-response []
  (let [start (atom 0)
        result (atom [])]
    (while (< (count @result) 50)
      (do
       (let [all-values (fetch @start)
             good-values (take-good-ones all-values)
             handled-this-time (count all-values)]
         (swap! start + handled-this-time)
         (swap! result concat good-values))))
   @result))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for mutating atoms or low-level looping stuff:

```
; the next 10 items since start
(defn fetch [start] 
   (range start (+ 10 start)))

; lazy sequence of good values, by getting batches of 10 from `fetch`
(defn all-good-values [] 
   (filter odd? 
      (mapcat #(fetch (* 10 %)) (range))))

(defn make-response [] 
   (take 20 (all-good-values)))

(make-response) => (1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39)
```

Comment: It's beautiful. Thank you. However how would you handle the situation where fetch function starts to return empty responses once the input reaches a certain value? For instance, if fetch returns empty values for any (start > 50) and in your make-response you issue a take 50? In that case calling make-response would not terminate. I love the succinctness of this lazy sequence stuff, but am having some difficulty in embracing it.

Comment: Hi @Mohamed an idiomatic way of handling this is to make sure the "source" sequence ends when fetch starts to return empty responses. Then the sequence processing function applying to the input (filter, take, etc) terminate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Further to [Joost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36177915/1562315), the batches are each filtered then concatenated, so the batching has no effect. So the effect is just

```
(defn make-response []
  (->> (range) (filter odd?) (take 50)))
```